# how does a c sharp compiler work when a function from the system namespace is called?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, namespaces, system

how does a c sharp compiler work when a function from any  pre-defined namespace is called?
I have mentioned System namespace just as an instance.

Answer (score 1):

The same as it does for any other namespace. There is no magic here.

There are *some* hard-coded things in the compiler, for example:

- the type aliases `int`/`string` etc which are merely aliases to `global::System.Int32` etc
- the expression tree compiler is, AFAIK, hard-coded to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` (but is also not cited in the spec, so a bit of an edge-case)
- some magic in the interop namespaces (for calling constructors on interfaces, etc)

But mostly... it is just classes etc.

Comment: Interesting re. hardcoded things, however he only mentioned `System` as an example, so probably *The same as it does for any other namespace* isn't enough of an explanation. I'd definitely appreciate a more detailed breakdown of the resolution process.

Comment: @George but the emphasis also seems to be on ***pre-defined*** namespace - where there really is no magic.